# Reading from a textfile and sorting the list afterwards

Tags: list, sorting, text-files

I have an assignment where I am required to read a file from a textfile and add the lines to a list, sort it by length and print it out. My problem is that Coolections.sort() sorts it both alphabetically and by length, I am required to only sort it by length, here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Question3
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String path = input.nextLine();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      while(scanner.hasNext())
      {
         lines.add(scanner.next());
      }
       Collections.sort(lines);
      System.out.println(lines);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                if(str1.length() > str2.length())
                    return 1;
                else if(str1.length() < str2.length())
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });
```

This will sort the strings based on their length in ascending order, please clean up the above code as required.